# Amenability and ultrafilters

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Among hundreds of equivalent definitions of amenability (for discrete, countable, groups), I would like to discuss two which are most common:

A1. A group $G$ is amenable if it admits a Folner sequence.

A2. A group $G$ is amenable if it admits an invariant mean.

(See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group or http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/some-notes-on-amenability/)

However, proofs of equivalence that I know (even for $G={\mathbb Z}$) require either axiom of choice or, at least, existence of a nonprincipal ultrafilter on ${\mathbb N}$.

Question: Is there a proof that A1 $\iff$ A2 which uses only ZF axioms? Or, maybe $A1\iff A2$ 
implies existence of nonprincipal ultrafilters, maybe in a weakened form?

This question was discussed a bit in [Why are abelian groups amenable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12169/why-are-abelian-groups-amenable) and [Why groups that admit Folner Sequences are amenable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93897/why-groups-that-admit-folner-sequences-are-amenable) but not in the above form.

Note: I am not a logician, but a geometric group-theorist and I frequently use ultrafilters. As the result I am often asked if the results could be proven without ultrafilters. For most proofs my answer usually is: "Yes, if you work much harder and write ugly and long proofs." However, I do not know the answer in the context of amenable groups.

Comment: Simon's answer is more complete, but an easy way to see that A1 does not imply A2 in ZF is to work in a model of ZF + all sets of reals have the property of Baire.  Certainly the integers will have a Folner sequence in this model, but a straightforward Baire category argument shows that no shift-invariant finitely additive probability measure on the integers is Baire measurable (as a function from $2^\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: In the previous comment I really meant ZFDC + BP to avoid silly pathologies.

Comment: @Clinton: Thank you for the answer. I am probably missing something simple, but how do you show non-existence of a finitely-additive Baire measurable probability measures on $2^{\mathbb Z}$? 

Comment: Misha, Here's a sketch of the argument I have in mind.  Let $f:2^\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ be our putative Baire measurable measure.  By generic ergodicity of the shift of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $2^\mathbb{Z}$, $f$ is constant on a comeager set.  Moreover, since complementation (in $\mathbb{Z}$, viewed as an automorphism of $2^\mathbb{Z}$) is a homeomorphism, WLOG we may assume this constant equals $1/2$.  Now fix dense open sets $U_n \subseteq 2^\mathbb{Z}$ whose intersection is contained in the $f$-preimage of $1/2$. [cont.]

Comment: Inductively build finite binary strings $u_n$, $v_n$, $w_n$ in $2^{[-k_n,k_n]}$ for some large $k_n$ such that (a) $u_n$, $v_n$, $w_n$ have disjoint supports, (b) the basic open neighborhood determined by $u_n$ (and $v_n$ and $w_n$) is contained in $U_n$, and (c) $u_{n+1}$ extends $u_n$ (and $v$ and $w$).  In the end, you've built strings $u$, $v$, $w$ in $\bigcap_n U_n$ of disjoint support, and thus three disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ each with measure $1/2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Clinton: Thank you, I understand most of it though I still have to learn more about generic ergodicity (beyond the definition). 

Comment: Misha, the use of generic ergodicity was really me being lazy, and isn't essential to the argument.  The main point is that following the outlined argument, you can build in any nonmeager BP subset of $2^\mathbb{Z}$ large finite collections of pairwise almost disjoint sets (any pair has finite intersection).  If you had a nontrivial Baire measurable measure $f$ on $2^\mathbb{Z}$, there'd be some $r>0$ with $f^{-1}([r,1])$ nonmeager (say $r = 1/2$), and by building enough almost disjoint sets you'd get a contradiction (I suppose all you need is for singletons to be null).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course, $ZF$ is enough to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a Folner sequence. But, as you point out, $ZF$ is not enough to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ has an invariant mean. Thus $ZF$ does not prove the equivalence of A1 and A2.

On the other hand, the Hahn-Banach Theorem is enough to prove the equivalence of A1 and A2 for countable discrete groups and Pincus-Solovay have constructed a model of $ZF$ in which the Hahn-Banach Theorem is true but there are no nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. Hence the equivalence of A1 and A2 for countable groups does not imply the existence of nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Simon: Yes, I know that Hahn-Banach theorem implies $A1\iff A2$ (I did not know though of the model where Hahn-Banach holds but Ultrafilter lemma does not). Did anybody actually prove that $A1\iff A2$ does not follow ZF only? It does not seem obvious to me...

Comment: Solovay constructed a model of ZF in which $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have an invariant mean. But, of course, $\mathbb{Z}$ has a Folner sequence in this model.